# Creating a vector of structs using command line arguments

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I am having some trouble understanding the process of creating this vector of structs. I am passing files into the program as parameters, and using their file locations to create a struct that contains this information. Is there a way to create the struct and add it to the vector using struct functions?

```
struct fileDetails
{
    string filePath;
    string fileName;
    string fileExt;

    void setFileDetails(char** path);
};

void fileDetails::setFileDetails(char** path)
{
    filePath = path.substr(0, path.find_last_of('\\'));
    fileExt = path.substr(path.find_last_of(".") + 1);
    fileName = path.substr(path.find_last_of('\\') + 1);
    fileName = fileName.substr(0, fileName.find_last_of('.'));
}

int main(int argc, char** argv[])
{
    vector<fileDetails> fileList;
    fileDetails fDet;

    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    {
        fDet.setFileDetails(argv[i]);
        fileList.push_back(fDet);
    }
}
```

Or what would be the better approach to this? I tried to do this using this format, but I am getting errors.

Comment: It looks reasonable on a quick scan. Post the errors.

Comment: @user3521733 Look again.

Comment: @0x499602D2: I think it'd be more useful to the OP to get help learning how to debug rather than to have others poring over his code.

Comment: Just change `char**` to `std::string`.

Comment: The errors I am getting are on the argv[i] in `fDet.setFileDetails(argv[i]);`

Comment: Okay, so the compiler is telling you that there is a type mismatch on that line. The compiler can't convert a char * to a char **. You passed a char *, but the parameter type is a char **.

Comment: Oh so then my main should look like this... `int main(int argc, char* argv[])`?

Comment: @user3521733, Yes, `int main(int argc, char* argv[])` is correct. While `int main(int argc, char** argv[])` is incorrect.

Comment: Okay, now that you've edited, yes, it should look like that. But passing in the argument `argv[i]` gives a `char*`, not a `char**`. The solution to that issue is to change the parameter type to `std::string`.

Comment: Wow okay I feel like an idiot. Been trying to figure this out for the last 2 hours, and I could have sworn I read it should be char** for C++. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Haha, I didn't even notice that main() was wrong. I just assumed that argv was declared as usual. That's why learning how to read error messages is important, and also why you should post them.

Comment: It can be char **. But you have char **[].

Answer (score 2):

You have two main errors.

First of all, `char**` does not have any `substr` member function. What you probably meant was to use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead:

```
void setFileDetails(std::string path);
//                  ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

And second, you have an unnecessary `*` in `argv`:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv[])
//                      ^
```

If you fix both, the program [will compile just fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/956cd57c780ff26e).

Comment: You could also remove the [] on char** argv[], which is the more traditional way of writing the main function.